# How to add foursixty app code to home page?

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<script data-for-url="true"
    data-open-links-in-same-page="false"
    data-feed-id="courtney-allegra-swim"
    src="//foursixty.com/media/scripts/fs.embed.v2.js">
</script>

<style>div.fs-has-links { text-indent: -9999px; position: static; font-weight: 500; } .fs-has-links::after {  padding:  14px 21px; border: 2px solid #fff; color:#fff; content: "SHOP NOW"; text-indent: 0; display: block; font-size: 10pt; margin: 10px; }.fs-desktop .fs-timeline-entry div.fs-text-container { display: flex; flex-direction: column;align-items: center; justify-content: center; display: -webkit-flex;  -webkit-flex-direction: column;  -webkit-align-items: center;  -webkit-justify-content: center;  display: -ms-flexbox;  -ms-flex-direction: column;  -ms-flex-align: center;  -ms-flex-pack: center; transition: opacity .25s; } .fs-desktop .fs-timeline-entry .fs-text-container:hover { opacity: 1; } .fs-wrapper div.fs-text-container .fs-entry-title, div.fs-detail-title{font-family:Times New Roman, serif;font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;}div.fs-text-container .fs-entry-date, div.fs-detail-container .fs-post-info, div.fs-wrapper div.fs-has-links::after, .fs-text-product, .fs-overlink-text{font-family:Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;}.fs-wrapper div.fs-text-container * {color:#fff}.fs-wrapper div.fs-text-container {background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); margin: 0px}div.fs-entry-date{display:none}div.fs-entry-title{display:none}.fs-wrapper div.fs-timeline-entry{ margin: 5px }</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the admin area go to CMS -> Pages, then find your home page, and then paste your code in the appropriate place.